# how can I find out the location from where the msi installer is being run

Tags: wix

Can anyone tell me how can I find out the location from where the msi installer is being run.

For example I have my `Sample.msi` and Manuals folder in the folder InstallerExample on the Desktop.

I need this information so that I can use it in File/@Source, like the one given below.

```
<File Id="MyFileId" Name="MyFile" Source="[SourceDir]Manuals" KeyPath="yes" >
```

`SourceDir` should have value `C:\Users\bla\Desktop\InstallerExample\Manuals`

It will be great if anyone can please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem as I wanted my custom action to read a file from where my MSI was so i needed the path. I was able to locate it using

```
TARGETDIR
```

According to the MSDN documentation TARGETDIR is

```
the root destination directory for the installation
```

Also according to MSDN, SourceDir is

```
the root directory that contains the source cabinet file or the source file tree of the installation package
```

So the SourceDir property points to a real directory: the one where your MSI file sits. You can see this in the installer log when installing with msiexec /lvx* installer.log installer.msi.

However, for some reason SourceDir is completely ignored when resolving the TARGETDIR. The TARGETDIR must be either set explicitly (e.g. on the command line) or else it resolves to ROOTDRIVE. If ROOTDRIVE is not explicitly set then it is the root of the drive with the most free space.

Comment: TARGETDIR : Points to the location where the Application is installed. And when I used SourceDir it points to a different location and it does not point to the location which has the msi file(in my case it does not have C:\Users\bla\Desktop\InstallerExample\Manuals). I basically want to determine the location the install MSI is running from. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Try the OriginalDatabase property, it is the path of the installation database used to launch the installation. Although I think this gets you the full path with the MSI at the end, but cannot test it at the minute.